# Random number generator confuses with srand function

Tags: random, generator, srand

I want to learn why my code is not working as I expect. I mean I want to generate a double number between 0 and 1 and I have learnt that when I use 
(double)rand() / RAND_MAX, it works well. However I read that srand(time(NULL))
changes each generated random number every time I compile. However When I use them together the program generates same random number all the time. Why does this happen? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
//srand(time(NULL));
number = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `srand()` function initializes the pseudo-random number generator. You can think of that like it is pointing to the `rand()` a number to start its 'calculations'. Every time you compile and run your program the `srand()` function gives your `rand()` function the seed of `time(NULL)` (which by the way is a very big number changing every second). If you don't use the `srand()`, your `rand()` will always return the same sequence of numbers because it is given by default a standart non-changing seed (number to start the 'calculations'). You can try to give your `srand()` a static parameter like: `srand(1500)` You will see that it will return different numbers but their sequence will again be the same every time u compile and run.

For more info read here:

> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/
>
> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/